# Solrcloud 5.5.5 with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrcloud

I have a requirement to upgrade to Solr 5.5.5 in my Solrcloud instance. I won't be touching Zookeeper version but will upgrade Tomcat version on each Solr server.

While going through notes for Solr 5 and above, I came across documentation that Solr can't guarantee that Solr will run in an external container like Tomcat and to use the in-built Jetty engine with Solr. Due to some security requirements, I cannot use Jetty and have to stick with Tomcat. I have some questions around this -

1. Has anyone been able to successfully run Solr 5 with Tomcat? Did you face any major issues?
2. Are there any resources on upgrading a Solrcloud instance like blogs or Solr provided documentation?
3. Should I roll with Jetty since Solr recommends that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, people are using Tomcat with recent versions of Solr, but this is not a supported configuration and you're on your own. If you're expecting help or resources suited for your use cases, they'll be fewer - and you might run into magic issues that there isn't any easily searchable solutions for. Whether this is acceptable is something you and your organization must decide, compared to the reasons for running Tomcat instead of the bundled jetty.

   The "exploded war / webapp" directory is usually available under `server/solr-webapp`, so you'll have to instruct Tomcat to load this instead of a war file.

   Be aware that you usually want to run an external Zookeeper ensemble for a SolrCloud installation. That is a separate daemon and not something that runs inside the application container.
2. There are usually [instructions in each reference manual for each version](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/upgrading-a-solr-cluster.html).
3. Yes.

Comment: Thank you.

We do have an external ZK setup from the beginning. I will take a look at the information that you have provided